# Manter valores selecionados de multiselect ao dar refresh na página?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Olá, tenho o código abaixo que é um multiselect por categoria. O que acontece é o seguinte, quando o usuário deixa de preencher um dado obrigatório, a página é recarregada e aparece a mensagem dizendo qual dado ele esqueceu, porém todos os dados já digitados continuam como estavam. Porém com o multiselect eu não estou conseguindo fazer isso, alguém tem alguma ideia?

```
        <div class="form-group"> 
          <label> Turno disponível <br />
          <select id='optgroup' multiple='multiple' name="dias[]">
            <optgroup label='Segunda-feira'>
              <option value='Segunda-feira 09:00 às 10:00'>09:00 às 10:00</option>
              <option value='Segunda-feira 10:00 às 11:00'>10:00 às 11:00</option>
              <option value='Segunda-feira 13:00 às 14:30'>13:00 às 14:30</option>
              <option value='Segunda-feira 15:00 às 16:00'>15:00 às 16:00</option>
              <option value='Segunda-feira 16:00 às 17:00'>16:00 às 17:00</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label='Terça-feira'>
              <option value='Terça-feira 09:00 às 10:00'>09:00 às 10:00</option>
              <option value='Terça-feira 10:00 às 11:00'>10:00 às 11:00</option>
              <option value='Terça-feira 13:00 às 14:30'>13:00 às 14:30</option>
              <option value='Terça-feira 15:00 às 16:00'>15:00 às 16:00</option>
              <option value='Terça-feira 16:00 às 17:00'>16:00 às 17:00</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label='Quarta-feira'>
              <option value='Quarta-feira 09:00 às 10:00'>09:00 às 10:00</option>
              <option value='Quarta-feira 10:00 às 11:00'>10:00 às 11:00</option>
              <option value='Quarta-feira 13:00 às 14:30'>13:00 às 14:30</option>
              <option value='Quarta-feira 15:00 às 16:00'>15:00 às 16:00</option>
              <option value='Quarta-feira 16:00 às 17:00'>16:00 às 17:00</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label='Quinta-feira'>
              <option value='Quinta-feira 09:00 às 10:00'>09:00 às 10:00</option>
              <option value='Quinta-feira 10:00 às 11:00'>10:00 às 11:00</option>
              <option value='Quinta-feira 13:00 às 14:30'>13:00 às 14:30</option>
              <option value='Quinta-feira 15:00 às 16:00'>15:00 às 16:00</option>
              <option value='Quinta-feira 16:00 às 17:00'>16:00 às 17:00</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label='Sexta-feira'>
              <option value='Sexta-feira 09:00 às 10:00'>09:00 às 10:00</option>
              <option value='Sexta-feira 10:00 às 11:00'>10:00 às 11:00</option>
              <option value='Sexta-feira 13:00 às 14:30'>13:00 às 14:30</option>
              <option value='Sexta-feira 15:00 às 16:00'>15:00 às 16:00</option>
              <option value='Sexta-feira 16:00 às 17:00'>16:00 às 17:00</option>
            </optgroup>
          </select>
        </label>
        </div>
```

Já tentei da forma abaixo, mas sem sucesso.

```
        <div class="form-group"> 
          <label> Turno disponível <br />
          <select id='optgroup' multiple='multiple' name="dias[]" <?php $example = $_GET["dias[]"];?>>
            <optgroup label='Segunda-feira'>
              <option <?php if (isset($example) && $example=="Segunda-feira 09:00 às 10:00") echo "selected";?> value='Segunda-feira 09:00 às 10:00'>09:00 às 10:00</option>
              <option value='Segunda-feira 10:00 às 11:00'>10:00 às 11:00</option>
              <option value='Segunda-feira 13:00 às 14:30'>13:00 às 14:30</option>
              <option value='Segunda-feira 15:00 às 16:00'>15:00 às 16:00</option>
                               .
                               .
                               .
                               .
```

Comment: Tenta mudar de `$_GET["dias[]"]` para `$_GET["dias"]`, mas alem disso verifica / mostra o que contem dentro de `$_GET["dias"]`